# Two-view geometry: why is rotating one camera causing a change in translation?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

there is an issue with epipolar geometry based pose estimation that's been really confusing me. I am using the OpenCV's implementation of David Nister's five point algorithm for computing the pose using point correspondences between images.

Let's say two cameras are separated by a baseline b: after doing the pose estimation, I get an up to scale t matrix that goes somewhat like [1,0,0]. Now, if I rotate one of the cameras by 30 degrees, no translation change (and assuming we still have sufficient feature matches), I would expect to see rotation angles like (0, 30, 0) and t matrix still being (1,0,0). But in my case, I am getting the correct R (0, 30 deg, 0), but t becomes something like (0.7, 0, 0.7): there's a change in the z translation. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you rotate camera 1 or camera 2? If you rotate camera 1, then you rotate the whole coordinate system. Now the center of camera 2 is no longer in the XY-plane.

Comment: ... can't believe I missed something that simple. Thank you, that's exactly what was happening: I got confused with the signs of the angles and I thought I was rotating the correct one.